# Activating an inactive workbook when the name is not known

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to make an open (but inactive) workbook active when the name of the workbook is not known? I'd like to build a macro in one workbook that when run brings up another open workbook and then executes the rest of the macro on that workbook.

Also, is there a way to select from among several open, inactive workbooks if the user has more than one open?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all workbooks in the application's workbooks collection:

```
var wb as workbook
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    If instr(1, wb.name, "hi") Then --activate a workbook if it's name has "hi" in it
        wb.activate
    End If

    'or

    If wb.name <> ThisWorkbook.name Then --find the first workbook that isn't this workbook
         wb.activate
    End If
Next
```

Basically, inside the loop you can test each workbook found (stored in the `wb` variable) and activate it depending on whatever property you want to test. This is about as specific as I can answer since you don't describe how you, as a human, would identify which workbook should be activated. You only say that you can't identify it by it's name.